# How to use symbol font in tkinter button ? python

Tags: python, tkinter, symbols

I try to make symbol button for use in Sci-notebook Python application.
But alpha show as "^"

```
    symbol = {'alpha':97,'beta':98,'gamma':103,'delta':100,\
             'epsilon':101,'zeta':122,'eta':104,'theta':113,\
                ..... }
    xp=0
    yp=0
    sym_button=[]
    for i in range(len(symbol.items())):
        cp=chr(symbol.items()[i][1])
        sym_button.append(tk.Button(frame1, width=1, height=1, font='Symbol 9', text=cp))
        sym_button[len(sym_button)-1].place(x=840+xp,y=0+yp)
        xp=xp+17
        if xp+840>960:
            xp=0
            yp=yp+25
```

I need to try something like or What?

```
      cp=chr(symbol.items()[i][1]).encode('Symbol')

      LookupError: unknow encoding: Symbol
```

Comment: Are you looking for UTF 8 characters ? (for Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta...)

Comment: cp=unichr(0xF000 + symbol.items()[i][1]) not work, It show as question mark [?] in the Button

Answer (score 2):

Relying on a special font for producing those symbols may not be the best way. Instead, you should consider directly using the respective unicode characters. You can find the character codes, e.g., on the Wikipedia pages for alpha, beta, etc.

Minimal example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
symbol = {'alpha':945, 'beta':946, 'gamma': 947, 'delta': 948, 'epsilon':949}
for s in symbol:
    tk.Button(root, text=unichr(symbol[s])).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, from your suggestion I find some Unicode to make many of symbol U0x2200 unichar 8704. My mistake come from dict not arrange but your answer look better. now I change to use list as symbol look like this symbol=[('alpha',945),('beta',946),('gamma',947),('delta',948),('epsilon',949)]